# Can anyone help me with a complex sum, 3 table join mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I have a query and it works fine, but I want to add another table to the mix. The *invite table* I want to add has two fields: **username** and **user_invite**. Much like this site, I am using a point system to encourage diligent users. The current query which is displayed below adds the up votes and down votes based on the user in question: **$creator**. I want to count the number of entries for that same user from the *invite table*, and add 50 for each row it finds to the current output/sum of my query. Is this possible with one query, or do I need two?

```
"SELECT *, 
SUM(IF(points_id = \"1\", 1,0))-SUM(IF(points_id = \"2\", 1,0)) AS 'total'
FROM points 
LEFT JOIN post ON post.post_id=points.points_id 
WHERE post.creator='$creator'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
SELECT *,**SUM(IF(points_id = "1", 1,0))-SUM(IF(points_id = "2", 1,0))+(select count(*)*50
from inivite where username='$creator') AS 'total'**,
FROM points LEFT JOIN post ON post.post_id=points.points_id WHERE post.creator='$creator'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Designing this query with limited knowledge of the schema...

`SELECT *,

SUM(IF(points_id = \"1\", 1,0))

-SUM(IF(points_id = \"2\", 1,0))

+ 50 * COUNT(invite.user_invite) AS 'total'` <--
`FROM points

LEFT JOIN post ON post.post_id=points.points_id` <--
`LEFT JOIN invite ON post.creator = invite.user_invite

WHERE post.creator='$creator'`

The important thing here is the extra lines, which I've marked with "<--". One is for JOINing your two tables together, the other is to modify the argument of the SUM function.

Post back if this doesn't work.

Comment: you forgot some brackets, but after modifying it, it does not quite work. There are two entries in invite, and a starting points of 4. The total should thus be 104 (4+50*2), however, I get 408. The 2nd left join seems to double the original points of 4 if I remove the 50*COUNT, and the count of the invite entries seems to double count to give a total of 400. Not sure why this would happen...it looks correct to me.

Comment: SUM and COUNT are applied to the whole result set, that is, the joined tables (restricted by where). By joining an additional table, you may - among other things - end up counting some of your points_ids serveral times, since they might appear several times in your joined table. Still only a guess, can't really say anything whithout knowing something more about your schema.

Comment: Oh, I see what happened -- at least with my query. I messed up the parens; it should be:

`SELECT *,  
SUM(IF(points_id = \"1\", 1,0))
- SUM(IF(points_id = \"2\", 1,0))  
+ 50 * COUNT(invite.user_invite) AS 'total'  
FROM...

I transposed a paren from `...2\", 1, 0))` to after `invite.user_invite)`. Fixed in my response now. THAT should work, I think...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there might be no correspondence in invite table, I used outer join and coalesce:

```
SET @good='1', @bad='2', @creator='$creator';

SELECT *, 
  SUM(IF(points_id=@good, 1,0))-SUM(IF(points_id=@bad, 1,0))+COALESCE(inv_cnt, 0) * 50) AS total
FROM points 
  LEFT JOIN post
    ON post.post_id=points.points_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT username, COUNT(user_invite) as inv_cnt
                   FROM invite
                   GROUP BY username) invites
    ON post.creator = invites.username
WHERE post.creator=@creator;
```